# "Source not found" when clicking on stacktrace

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java-9

Usually, clicking on a line in the stacktrace, the source file opens at the offending line. With Eclipse-oxygen (R with support for java9 installed) and java9 (u175) it shows a dialog "Source not found" if the source is somewhere inside the java modules. Source is found as expected, when navigating (by F3) in the editor.

What's/where's wrong and how-to fix it?

Below is a simple two-liner example which fails, showing the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out-of-bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:453)
    at dummy.PlainStacktrace.main(PlainStacktrace.java:10)
```

The two-liner:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlainStacktrace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.set(5, "error");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an eclipse bug to me. I would rather invest in writing a bug report ...

Comment: so you can reproduce it?

Comment: Nope. I am saying I wouldn't spend time here, but rather look into eclipse forums or their bug tracker.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the suggestion, but .. well ([forum header](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/22/): "Future of Eclipse Forums
We are considering archiving the Eclipse forums, as there are now many better options available. Please see and comment on Bug 451571." And that bug contains many comments as why/how the eclipse forum is inadequate ;)

Comment: Where is the relationship to JavaFX?

Comment: @Holger not exactly this but certainly the follow-up ;) It's a chain of failure experiences triggered by fx development .. and I could have used a fx example to provide the obvious connection ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [bug 518829](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518829), which should be resolved in recent builds.

NB: until Java 9 and Eclipse support for it are officially released, it may be a good idea to regularly updated not only JDK but also the Eclipse part.

Comment: hmm .. I thought the java9 patch (and the rest) was current until last night (1.1.1.v20170627-0530_BETA_JAVA9) but anyway updated (or at least tried to ;) to 1.1.1v20170731-0938_BETA_JAVA9 which indeed enabled finding the sources inside modules from stacktrace but somehow wrecked eclipse completely, getting a steady error stream of "error in jdt core during ast creation problems occured when invoking codefrom plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui" and weird compile errors on javafx :(( Will give up for now, **not** update and live with source-not-found until the patch is patched ... thanks

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your problems. I could try to explain by pointing to fundamental changes which appeared in JLS only some weeks ago (which turned a key aspect of the compiler implementation upside down), but more importantly: if you want to be sure that "your" problems are fixed, please consider filing one or more bugs at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Core ... thanks.

Comment: thanks for caring :)) will wait a bit and try to find the nerves in the near future to try and narrow it down a bit and then file a bug (the latest patch definitely doesn't work even with a clean installation of oxygen-r and the most recent ea 9_180, all win32 bit)

Comment: I was able to install the patch and use it on 32 bit eclipse oxygen, so definitely a bug report with more information would help. The patch is tested with a specific jdk version (which is specified in the market place), so sticking to that is recommended. The market place page is updated regularly when there's a new patch build available.